# I cannot push to GitHub

Tags: github

[image: remote: Invalid username or password]

I cannot push to github
it ask for username and password
and after i provide them
that shows it is wrong (see in the image)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Do you need to [create a personal access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to use instead of a password for HTTPS authentication? You can also set up an SSH key to use instead if you're having trouble with HTTPS. Finally I'm not sure you want the trailing / on the remote URL, but I doubt that would matter yet.

Comment: However if that's not it, and you need someone to investigate your GitHub account then you'll have to ask GitHub directly.